# I get this Error when trying to run a PhpUnit test on my Drupal project

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, drupal, phpunit

TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\views\Plugin\views\HandlerBase::__construct() must be of the type array phpunit

My code is:

```
use Drupal\views_simple_math_field\Plugin\views\field\SimpleMathField;

class BasicTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   public function test_proba()
   {
     $first = 25;
     $second = 5;
     $result = 13;
     $test = new SimpleMathField();
     $working = $test->plus($first,$second,$result);
     $this->assertEquals($result,$working);

 }
}
```

I think the error is within " $test = new SimpleMathField(); because the test runs perfectly when I run it like this:

```
<?php

use Drupal\views_simple_math_field\Plugin\views\field\SimpleMathField;

class BasicTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   public function test_proba()
   {
     $first = 25;
     $second = 5;
     $result = 13;
    $this->assertTrue(True);

 }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing a class named Basic?

Comment: I am testing a plus() function in SimpleMathFIeld class which is located in extern PHP File that has Drupal\views_simple_math_field\Plugin\views\field\ namespace.

Comment: A test class should have a name suffixed with "Test". So it should be  SimpleMathFIeldTest instead of BasicTest. If you are not absolutely sure what you're doing, I would recommend this excellent tutorial: https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-introduction-to-phpunit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your test, but how you instantiate the field. Through a chain of abstraction the class extends [HandlerBase](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.4.x/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/HandlerBase.php#L93) and the constructor linked looks like this:

```
public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->is_handler = TRUE;
}
```

You could try something like this:

```
new SimpleMathField(array(), 'test_id', 'test_definition');
```

You probably have to check in the `plus()` method if some of these variables passed to __construct or initialized by them is needed in there. You could also try something called partial mocking, where you disable the constructor but keep the tested method in test:

```
$partiallyMockedField = $this->getMockBuilder(SimpleMathField::class)
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods([])
    ->getMock();
```

You might have to add some methods you need to be mocked in the array. Those will be replaced with whatever you specify using `expects()` and `method()` in your typical mocks.

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if you have to pass an empty array or an explicit null to setMethods to make this work as I rarely use partial mocking myself. You have to check the docs or try yourself.

Comment: Much appreciate
I can't upvote though, still have low reputation.